# Is it possible to interpolate Javascript regex match in a string template?

Tags: javascript, regex

For example... (this fails)

```js
const currencyMap = {
  "$": "USD",
  "€": "EUR",
};

const r = '$100'.replace(/(\$)([0-9]*)/g, `${currencyMap[$1]}$2`);
console.log(r);
```

Is there a way to make this sort of thing work?
`$1` is available when it's used in a string, but not as a key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately no, you'll have to use a replacer function instead:

```js
const currencyMap = {
    "$": "USD",
    "€": "EUR",
};

const r = '$100'.replace(/(\$)(\d*)/g, (_, $1, $2) => currencyMap[$1] + $2);
console.log(r);
```

Also note that you can use `\d` instead of `[0-9]` instead, it makes the regex a bit nicer to read.

If you don't *actually need* the second group for something special, you can just echo back the match in the object:

```js
const currencyMap = {
    "$": "USD",
    "€": "EUR",
};

const r = '$100'.replace(/[$€]/g, match => currencyMap[match]);
console.log(r);
```

Comment: So on the first example the replacer function is: `_`?

Comment: In both, the replacer function is the second argument to `.replace`. In the first, that function is `(_, $1, $2) => currencyMap[$1] + $2`

Answer (score 2):

Ok I've figured it out. Replace can take a function as a second arg to make the replacement string.

```
const currencyMap = {
    "$": "USD",
    "€": "EUR",
};

const r = '$100'.replace(/(\$)([0-9]*)/g, (full, first, second) => {
    return `${currencyMap[first]} ${second}`;
});

console.log(r);
```